# Having problems on using appcache on Android Webview

Tags: java, android, jquery, html, webview

I'm working on a mobile application that uses Webview to access a jQuery Mobile page, the problem is the Appcache is not saving my page, but it does save on browsers though, I've been searching for solutions, but none of them seemed to work in my case.

Any help is deeply appreciated!

**Here's my `Webview` code:**

```
package com.enlac.tasking;

import java.io.File;

import com.enlac.tasking.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebStorage;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        String sDataPath = this.getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
        webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(sDataPath);
        webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
        File dir = getCacheDir();
        if (!dir.exists()) {
          dir.mkdirs();
        }
        webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(dir.getPath());
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new webChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("I removed the link because I don't have the rights to show some stuff on it");



    }
    private class Callback extends WebViewClient{  

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return (false);
        }

 }
 private class webChromeClient extends WebChromeClient
 {
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
        public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize, long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) { 
         quotaUpdater.updateQuota(50 * 1024 * 1024); 
     }       
 }

}
```

**Android Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.enlac.tasking"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.enlac.tasking.WebViewActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="com.enlac.tasking.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```